# Minimum diode current / realtime clock battery backup

Tags: batteries, diodes

I know there is a minimum forward voltage for diodes, however, is there a similar property for current? I'm trying to use something like a BAT54C as a steering diode such that a 3V lithium battery acts as a backup power source, so my current will be in the range of 0.7uA. My application is in powering a DS1347 Realtime Clock IC, which does not have an independent Vbat input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there's no minimum current for a diode. They're often rated at several mA, like for instance 10 mA, but that's because most users will use them in that range and then it's good to know what the forward voltage is.

[image]

At very low currents the voltage drop will also be low, to less than 100 mV even; the graph for the BAT54 says 150 mV at 100 µA and 25 °C. Either way, the DS1347 will operate at voltages between 2 V and 5 V so you won't have to worry too much about the voltage drop.